# Jasper Reports - Add one day to a Date Parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm creating a Jasper report that includes the following parameters:

- **DATESTART** (Date)
- **DATEEND** (Date)

These parameters indicate a date range for a field called **DATECREATED** (Timestamp) which includes times.  I would like the date range to be INCLUSIVE, that is, if I filter for "Jan 1, 2009" to "Jan 31, 2009", any DATECREATED value on Jan 31, 2009 (such as "Jan 31, 2009 15:00") will be included in the report.

When I used Crystal Reports in the past, I used the DATEADD function to create a filter expression like the following:

```
{DATECREATED} >= {DATESTART} and {DATECREATED} < DATEADD("d", 1, {DATEEND})
```

(I realize that this isn't syntactically correct, but you get the idea.)

Is there any way to do something similar in Jasper Reports?

Comment: Note that there is the EDATE function which adds a number of *months* to a date, but there does not appear to be a similar function to increment days only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you understand French, there the same question is asked in [this thread](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d757148/logiciels/solutions-dentreprise/business-intelligence/jasper/ireport/operation-date/)
(the only difference is that it is about adding a month)

The proposed solutions are following:

### SQL

Do it with SQL statement directly in the query (if your data source is a SQL datasource of course).
With MySQL you can do something like

```
DATE_ADD($P{DATEEND},INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

more information: [Date and Time Functions (MySQL doc)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

### JAVA

The other solution is to use the Java possibly of the [Date object](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

I proposed something like :

```
$P{DATEEND}.setDay($P{DATEEND}.getDay()+1)
```

But I did not try it (and it is probably wrong).

Maybe you need to defined a new Date Variable DATEEND_1
with a value expression like :

```
new Date($P{DATEEND}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)
```

or

```
new java.util.Date($P{DATEEND}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)
```

And use this new variable in your query `V{DATEEND_1}`.

(again I am not sure of it)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`new java.util.Date($P{DATEEND}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Groovy SDK that comes bundled with the latest versions.

```
new Date().plus(1) //Today plus one day = tomorrow.
```

Or to be more complete - add your two parameters DATESTART and DATEEND and set the default expression to be the above code. Then in your query add the following to the where clause:

```
DATECREATED >= $P{DATESTART} and DATECREATED < $P{DATEEND}
```

or depending on your SQL variant.

```
DATECREATED BETWEEN $P{DATESTART} AND $P{DATEEND}
```

Comment: Using Groovy is so much easier than native java date functions!

Comment: I tried this, and it says "The method plus(int) is undefined for the type of Date"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Parameter `PARAM1`  and you want to add 366 days to param1 then you can do it by following way

1) Declare another parameter say `$P{finalDate}`

2) Code like below for `$P{finalDate}` as the Default Value Expression

```
new Date($F{PARAM1}.getTime() + 366L*24*60*60*1000)
```

Dont forget to put  L after 366 . Without putting L , it may not work properly and may not give accurate date.

It will add 366 days to PARAM1

Answer (score 1):

We have built a library of static date-related functions, which can be used like this:

```
DateUtil.add(NOW(), 0, 0, 1)
```

The above would get you a date one day into the future (the arguments are year, month, day). It would be nice to have a DATE_ADD function supported directly by JasperReports. Sounds like a patch waiting to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

```
DAYSINMONTH($P{Date}) >= (DAY($P{Date})+ 1) 
? 
DATE(YEAR($P{Date}),MONTH($P{Date}),DAY($P{Date})+1) 
:
((MONTH($P{Date}) + 1) > 12) ? DATE(YEAR($P{Date}) + 1,1,1) : DATE(YEAR($P{Date}),MONTH($P{Date}) +1 ,1)
```

I am sorry for necro'ing this post but I thought that I should share this as another alternative to the options posted above. You just need to change all the `$P{Date}` to be your parameter!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to help you, which has a static method which processes your parameters (or modify class JasperUtils by adding a static method). This way you can have amethod returning a boolean which will act exactly as the filter you need.

```
package com.package_name.utils;

public class JasperUtils2 {
  public static Boolean filterDate(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd, Date dateCreated) {
    if (dateCreated.compareTo(dateStart) < 0) return false; // dateCreated is greater or
                                                            // equal to dateStart
    if (dateCreated.compareTo(dateEnd) > 0) return false; // dateCreated is smaller or
                                                          // equal to dateEnd   
    // you can combine the two conditions into one. I wrote it like this to be more obvious
  }
}
```

To use this method, you need to import the class created (Edit -> Report import directives -> new import    ---- this may differ for different versions of iReport). Then, you can use the method in static way:

JasperUtils2.filterDate(..., ..., ...)