# Jaspersoft Dataset query - Add year parameter

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

I'm designing a report which will be used as subreport. The Main report has only two parameters

1. Project ID(param_projId)
2. Year(param_year)

So I'm planning to use the same in Subreport. But I've issues passing just the Year parameter in Date part of the query. For example.

```
select taskname, 
        taskstartdate, 
        taskenddate 
 from   TASK PT, 
        project prj 
 where prj.project id = $P{param_projId} and 
       PT.taskstartdate>= $P{param_year}-01-01 00:00:00.0 and 
       PT.taskenddate <= $P{param_year}-12-31 00:00:00.0
```

I'm getting the Oracle error. I'm having issues passing just the Year parameter to the date. Any advice on how to format the date as requested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Date - How to add years to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313234/oracle-date-how-to-add-years-to-date)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to pass the Year parameter in the above format.As the year parameter is used in the Main report too, I would like to use the same in the subreport. Hence in the query i need to pass as above. If there's any other way to use the Year parameter append with 1st of Jan and 31st of Dec???

Comment: `If there's any other way to use the Year parameter append with 1st of Jan and 31st of Dec?` - Yes

Comment: Another link: [Jasper Reports - Add one day to a Date Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675272/876298)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying the following `PT.taskstartdate >= to_date($P{param_year}||'"/01/01"', '"YYYY-MM-DD"' ) ` But it still fails with the error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string. :(

Comment: What is a type of `$P{param_year}`? Did you try to use `$!P{}` expression? Why you are using different delimiters ('/' in first argument of `to_date` function and the '-' in the second one)? You should not forget that you are using `YYYY` format - it is 4 digitals year view

Comment: Thanks. I've solved the issue using the command `PT.taskstartdate >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE($P{param_year}||'-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue using the command `PT.taskstartdate >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE($P{param_year}||'-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`